# t-SQL UPDATE table after adding columns to it with ADD TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table

I have to add several columns to the table and then update them in SQL Server 2008. The table definition boils down to this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
                  dvt NVARCHAR(32), 
                  dd NVARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(1, '1', NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(2, '', NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(3, '2,5', NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(4, '13, 34, 45, 5', NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(5, '-1, 8, 10', NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, dd) 
 VALUES(6, '-2, -10', NULL);
```

How do I add data to the table in the same transaction that created the table?

Comment: Now that you've changed your code, the sentence after the code block (`I get an error: "Invalid column name 'd0"`) makes no sense. It would be better if you rolled back your question to the previous version and posted your solution *as an answer*.

Comment: Sorry, man. Someone just below suggested that I update it in my original post. Now you tell me to roll it back.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted your update, then. I thought you found a solution and changed the code in your question to indicate that. If the problem isn't solved yet, fine, but is the error message `Invalid column name 'd0` still relevant? You posted it before modifying the code, and you didn't remove it after the last update.

Comment: No, I did find the solution and it's posted above. I updated the original question to make it less confusing. So this post is now technically becomes a "statement."

Comment: Sorry @AndriyM, he said the new code (which was the result of the answer below and subsequent comments) was not working, so I asked him to post the exact *new* code in the question. I intended it to be an additional sample, not an edit to the original. I guess I need to be much, much, much more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON     
**--BEGIN TRANSACTION** 

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d0 SMALLINT NULL 
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d1 SMALLINT NULL 
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d2 SMALLINT NULL 

GO

UPDATE tbl 
 SET 
 d0 = 1, 
 d1 = 2, 
 d2 = 3 

**--COMMIT TRANSACTION** 
SET XACT_ABORT OFF 

SELECT * FROm tbl
```

Without the transaction

Comment: Thanks. But I need the whole bunch to execute atomically (or in one transaction)?

Comment: OK, try it with the transaction included, but with the GO where I placed it, that should work.

Comment: Forgot to say, there's also an IF statement enclosing the whole sequence. When I add GO to it it says invalid syntax near UPDATE. (Sorry, for adjusting it post-fact)

Comment: Then you might have to have the same if condition twice, with the go statement inbetween, and the alter in the first and the update in the second.

Comment: Sorry, still no go. In SQL Fiddle I get "Explicit commits are not allowed." and in my actual SQL Server Express 2008 I get "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

Comment: Stop testing this in SQLFiddle, and test it in SQL Server. I don't mean to say that SQLFiddle is bad, in fact in can be quite useful, but there are some differences in how it behaves compared to Management Studio (as evidenced by the different error messages you're getting). So we don't have to guess, instead of saying "no go," can you update the question with a code sample representing the new code that is failing? We can't fix code we can't see, and have no way to know how you translated @astander's suggestion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: OK, sorry. Updated the sample in my question. I'm not sure if it matters, in my real example I execute these statements via ASP.NET code?

Comment: OK, guys, nevermind. I got it to work. Updated the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @ahmd0 You found one of the few differences between SQL Fiddle and the stock databases.  Explicit commits cause problems for sharing in SQL Fiddle, so I've specifically disabled that functionality.

Comment: @JakeFeasel: I'm glad I was able to contribute indirectly )) BTW, great job on SQLFiddle! In despite what other have said I prefer to test my SQL with it. The major selling point for me is its easy UI vs clunky Microsoft's SQL Server.

Comment: @ahmd0 I don't think Aaron was speaking otherwise - he is correct in pointing out that in this particular case, it didn't serve your needs.  Thanks for the kind praise!

Answer (score 2):

The update statement must be enclosed in `EXEC()` block.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON     
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF 1=1 BEGIN  --used for simplicity to illustrate condition

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d0 SMALLINT NULL 
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d1 SMALLINT NULL 
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD d2 SMALLINT NULL 

EXEC('UPDATE tbl SET d0 = 1, d1 = 2, d2 = 3')

END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT OFF 

SELECT * FROm tbl
```

(This answer is actually ahmd0's answer, hence posting it as community wiki.  However, his putting his answer in his question made it difficult for googlers like myself to idenitfy (and upvote) the answer we like.)